# How to create a ListView inside onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have a GridView which, when an element is clicked, shows its text, as can be seen below.

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //code
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

When an item is clicked, instead of showing a simple text, I'd like the app to "pop up" a list, such that the user can choose an option which I would handle. I'm not even sure if ListView is what I'm supposed to be looking for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Pop an alert dialog with a listview as its body.

Answer (score 0):

[Documents.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)
Or just the example code:

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

P.S. add `.show();` after the create to immidiate show the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a [Dialog Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment), which is a Dialog (pop-up) with a custom layout.

An example:

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_choice_list, null);

    mList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.your_list);

    final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, mList);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(getArguments().getInt("title") + "").setView(v);

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
    builder.setMessage(strName);
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```